# Pivots,column dependence & free/basic variables (General topic)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it correct to say that pivots must be handled correctly,so that one can form the U matrix(like,making the correct row operations in order not to "destroy" the zeroes one has built,so then the system can be solved using recursive substitution)?

How are pivots connected to the idea of column dependence?

Lastly,why are pivot related columns considered as the basic variables,whereas the remaining columns are considered as the free variables?

(for example: if y is a basic variable,and w is a free variable suppose the equation : y=w+4 but <=> w=y-4.I know it's not correct,but why can't i say that y & w switched roles?)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Pivot should be handled correctly so that you have a systematic way to solve a linear system.

The columns of the original matrix corresponding to the pivot positions is a basis to its column space, they are linearly independent.

Let $N$ be the set of free variable.
The pivot variable can be set as linear combination of the other variable. $x_i = -\sum_{j>i, j \in N}\hat{A}_{ij}x_j$ where $\hat{A}_{ij}$ is the corresponding row echelon form.  Once we fix the value of those $x_j$, we totally determine $x_i$. Those $x_j$ can be chosen freely.  The standard procedure tell us that we can systematically fix the free variables to determine the pivot entries.

You can swith the role of $y$ and $w$. Choose the value of $y$ and determine $w$. However, after you do that, you then have to look at the other position that $w$ appears in the other rows. In contrast, for the standard procedure, you can directly fix all the other free variables and solve the pivot entries in parallel.